# php - Codeigniter Rest api simple CRUD

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-restapi

I have this problem with inserting data to MySQL which require POST method by using postman.

this function `data_post()` inserts data from database, but when I am trying to insert data raw data with postman

```
{"id":"2","name":"ropen","password":"pamela005"}
```

I am having this error on postman:

> 405 Method not Allowed

**This is my Controller**
`Users.php`

```
public function data_post(){
    $params = [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'John Doe',
        'password' => 'test'
    ];
    $resp = $this->user_model->data($params);
    $this->set_response($resp, REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED);    
}
```

**Model**
`User_model.php`

```
public function data($data){   
      $this->db->insert('user',$data);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*You have to get `post` data using `$this->post()` first , should be like this :*

**Note** : if your `id` column is autoincrement there is no need to add id in `$params`

```
public function data_post()
{
    $id = $this->post('id');
    $name = $this->post('name');
    $password = $this->post('password');

    $params = array('id' => $id,'name' => $name,'password' => $password);
    $resp = $this->user_model->data($params);
    $this->set_response($resp, REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED);    
}
```

For more : https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver#handling-requests

Comment: do  update and delete in the same way, just try if u face any problem then post a new question

Comment: r u using  postman to update the data, if yes just get data using `$this->post() ` and then update it

Comment: Im having problems with update and delete method I dont know why, It returns Data has been deleted or updated but when I look into my database nothing happens

Comment: public function update_users($id,$data)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id)->update('user',$data);
        return array('status' => 200,'message' => 'Data has been updated.');
    }

    public function delete_users($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id)->delete('user');
        return array('status' => 200,'message' => 'Data has been deleted.');
    }

Comment: for now, yes I am using postman. After this code works I am going to use android and .net c# later

Comment: what column name and id you r sending with post request?

Comment: name and password

Comment: do a post request and your delete method should be like this  : `public function delete_post() 
{ 
    $id = $this->post('id');
    $this->db->where('id',$id)->delete('user'); 
    return array('status' => 200,'message' => 'Data has been deleted.'); 
} `

Comment: it works thanks. but why  _delete() method does not work?

Comment: sorry I only have 13 reputation I'll upvote it later if I get 15+ reputation